# Review pending edit window sized incorrectly on mobile (Safari on iOS 5)

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, design, ipad

The other day I was viewing a question on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) on my iPad and noticed there was a suggested edit on the question. I clicked the "edit" link, and a window popped up to show me the proposed edit. While users viewing this window are *supposed* to choose "approve," "reject," "improve," or "skip," there's also supposed to be an "X" button on the upper left side to just close out of the window. That close button is cut off in mobile Safari, and I'm not able to zoom the page when this popup is open. Can we fix the size of the edit window so the close button is visible/tappable?

[image: mobile edits]